# javax.annotation.security.RolesAllowed cannot be found in JSF + Spring 3 WebApplication

Tags: jsf, spring-security

I'm trying to add Spring 3.1.2 Security to an existing JSF Application, the problem is that this annotation cannot be found and I have no idea which dependency is missing there. any help is appreciated:

POM.xml

```
<properties>
    <myfaces.version>2.1.8</myfaces.version>
    <spring-security.version>3.1.2.RELEASE</spring-security.version>
</properties>

        <!-- Spring Security -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-core</artifactId>
            <version>${spring-security.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
            <version>${spring-security.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-acl</artifactId>
            <version>${spring-security.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-web</artifactId>
            <version>${spring-security.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-taglibs</artifactId>
            <version>${spring-security.version}</version>
        </dependency>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't mention what app server you are deploying to, so I'm assuming Tomcat, which doesn't typically have all / Java EE dependencies. If you're only looking for the annotations you can simply grab the JSR250 API dependency:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.annotation</groupId>
    <artifactId>jsr250-api</artifactId>
    <version>1.0</version>
</dependency>
```

You could also pull in the full Java EE 6 API:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax</groupId>
    <artifactId>javaee-api</artifactId>
    <version>6.0</version>
</dependency>
```